# Highlight Every 5 Minute Candle in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I only want to highlight every XX:05 & XX:35 Minute candle during a 24H Trading Session (Up Candle Green and Down Candle Red)

Example:
16:05 Candle Green
16:35 Candle Red
17:05 Candle Red
17:35 Candle Green

and so on for the whole trading day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `minute` built-in variable to figure out the current bar minute.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("05", overlay=true)

is_05 = (minute % 5) == 0

bgcolor(is_05 ? color.new(color.blue, 85) : na)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Do you know if there is a way to colour the candles purple if bearish and lime if bullish?

I think there needs to be a function which checks for each candle if Open Price is higher or lower than closing price?

Comment: There is a way but you should ask a new question for that.